# SpriteKit - method similar to getChildByName/getChildByTag in Cocos2d

Tags: sprite-kit

Now started porting game from Cocos2d to Sprite-Kit as Cocos2d not offers box2d physics and new version of Cocos2d 3.0 has less features.

Got struct with some place while porting it to Sprite-Kit. Is there any way to get child node from parent in SpriteKit ?

```
    (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:2022]; //cocos2d syntax
```

How can I achieve this in Sprite-Kit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Apple documentation on SKNode:

[– childNodeWithName:](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/childNodeWithName%3a)

[– enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName%3ausingBlock%3a)

Also see SKNode's [userData](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData) property.